# Qual a diferença entre cursor: no-drop e not-allowed no CSS

Tags: css, css3

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre os valores `no-drop` e `not-allowed` da propriedade `cursor` do **CSS**.

```css
span{
  font-size: 30px;
}

.not-allowed{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.no-drop{
  cursor: no-drop;
}
```

```html
<span class="not-allowed">not-allowed</span><br>
<span class="no-drop">no-drop</span><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na teoria:

> not-allowed: Não permite que uma ação seja executada/chamada.
>
> no-drop: Informa o browser (e o usuário - através do elemento visual) que não é possível executar uma ação de drag n' drop.

Enquanto visualmente podem parecer a mesma coisa, no quesito funcional elas possuem essa diferença.

Dependendo do browser, elas podem ter até o efeito visual diferente. No chrome e firefox (se não me engano) são iguais, mas já no IE, é diferente.

#### Editado:

Aqui tem a lista completa de todos os tipos de cursores e os browsers que eles são compatíveis: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: Mais qual deles é compatível com todos os browsers?

Comment: @Danilo editei a resposta para responder isso.

Comment: Estava com essa dúvida há algum tempo, valeu.